# How can we see the threads in Celery?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, celery, celery-task, celeryd

I am trying to set a different number of concurrent threads in Celery using `--concurrency=1` (based on [Workers Guide](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#concurrency)).

Anyway, when I run the daemon (`celeryd ... --concurrency=1`) I don't know how to see the number of threads that are running.

Do they correspond to each line shown in `ps -ef`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default celery uses subprocesses for the workers. If you configure `concurrency=1` you should have 2 processes:

- the main process that consumes messages from the broker and manages the process poll
- 1 worker process

In general you will have 1 main process + N worker subprocesses, as many as stated in `--concurrency=N` or `CELERYD_CONCURRENCY=N`

I'm not sure what happens with gevent workers.

Comment: When you say `CELERYD_CONCURRENCY=N`, do you mean that this parameter can be put in celeryconfig.py? Thanks!

Comment: Yep, you can put it in celeryconfig.py or in the command line. If you use both the command line overrides the configuration file.

Comment: What about the threads used for this process? How can we configure threads used for each process? In my case, where concurrency is 8
ps -ef | grep celery | grep -v grep | wc -l returns 8 and ps -eLf | grep celery | grep -v grep | wc -l returns 34

Answer (score 1):

`ps -ef | grep celery | grep -v grep | wc -l` returns the number of celery process running which is equal to the concurrency and
`ps -eLf | grep celery | grep -v grep | wc -l` returns the number of threads used by celery